# Failed to execute npm start

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, vagrant

I have setup a vagrant virtual machine and installed nodejs (v 6.9.1) and npm (v 4.0.0). Cloned a nodejs app with git clone and executed `npm install` command in root folder as well as app folder. However when I try to start the app via `npm start`, it fails

Stack:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/work/newair/app$ npm start -verbose
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ '/usr/bin/nodejs', '/usr/bin/npm', 'start', '-verbose' ]
npm info using npm@4.0.0
npm info using node@v6.9.1
npm verb run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
npm info lifecycle pykihAIR@0.4.0~prestart: pykihAIR@0.4.0
npm info lifecycle pykihAIR@0.4.0~start: pykihAIR@0.4.0

> pykihAIR@0.4.0 start /home/vagrant/work/newair/app
> electron main.js


npm verb lifecycle pykihAIR@0.4.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
npm verb lifecycle pykihAIR@0.4.0~start: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/home/vagrant/work/newair/app/node_modules/.bin:/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin:/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/bin:/home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/vagrant/.rvm/bin:/home/vagrant/.rvm/bin
npm verb lifecycle pykihAIR@0.4.0~start: CWD: /home/vagrant/work/newair/app
npm info lifecycle pykihAIR@0.4.0~start: Failed to exec start script
npm verb stack Error: pykihAIR@0.4.0 start: `electron main.js`
npm verb stack Exit status 1
npm verb stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:277:16)
npm verb stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
npm verb stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
npm verb stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:40:14)
npm verb stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
npm verb stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
npm verb stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
npm verb stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
npm verb pkgid pykihAIR@0.4.0
npm verb cwd /home/vagrant/work/newair/app
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-100-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "start" "-verbose"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v4.0.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! pykihAIR@0.4.0 start: `electron main.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the pykihAIR@0.4.0 start script 'electron main.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the pykihAIR package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     electron main.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs pykihAIR
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls pykihAIR
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm verb exit [ 1, true ]

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/vagrant/work/newair/app/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Is there a `main.js` file inside `/home/vagrant/work/newair/app` ? Can you run `electron` inside the same directory ?

Comment: Yes. `main.js` is present inside the app folder

Comment: Does the `electron main.js` command work ?

Comment: No. `electron main.js` does not work

Answer (score 0):

After discussing through the comments, it seems that the `electron` package is not installed.

You can install locally by running `npm install --save electron`, use the `--save` flag to write it's definition inside your `package.json` file.

If you want it to be global, you can run `npm install -g electron`, you'll be able to execute it anywhere else on your machine.

Comment: I did install `electron` package while setting up the app as well as globally. Execution of `electron main.js` does not throw any errors or start the app.

Comment: No. same problem with `./node_modules/.bin/electron`

Comment: Can you retry `npm install --save electron` under the same directory and tell if there's a problem then ?

Comment: ` pykihAIR@0.4.0 /home/vagrant/work/newair/app
├─┬ electron@1.4.4
│ └─┬ electron-download@3.0.1
│   ├─┬ fs-extra@0.30.0
│   │ ├── jsonfile@2.4.0
│   │ └── klaw@1.3.0
│   ├── minimist@1.2.0
│   ├─┬ nugget@2.0.1
│   │ └─┬ single-line-log@1.1.2
│   │   └─┬ string-width@1.0.2
│   │     ├── code-point-at@1.0.1
│   │     └── is-fullwidth-code-point@1.0.0
│   ├── path-exists@2.1.0
│   └─┬ sumchecker@1.2.0
│     └── es6-promise@3.3.1
└── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY electron-prebuilt@1.3.5

npm WARN electron-process@0.2.0 requires a peer of electron-prebuilt@^0.36.4 but none was installed.`

Comment: It throws error `UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY electron-prebuilt@1.3.5`

Comment: You have to remove `electron-prebuilt` from `package.json`, it's being deprecated, forget `electron-prebuilt` completely and use `electron` instead.